# connect to SQL Server Database with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, wamp, wampserver

I want to connect to a specific database on SQL Server Through PHP. On WAMP Server, I have PHP 5.6 installed so I downloaded SQLSRV32.EXE (Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server) then I copied these files in C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.25\ext
[image]

IN php.ini, I added

> extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
>
> extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll

But when i check phpinfo() on browser i don't see the sqlsrv module listed.

When i try to connect to my SQL Server Database I get this error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()

Here is my code

```
<?php
$serverName = "PC0CFEP2\SQLEXPRESS"; //serverName\instanceName

// Since UID and PWD are not specified in the $connectionInfo array,
// The connection will be attempted using Windows Authentication.
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"test");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

I was checking my solutions on different forums and I tried many but I still can't get it work. I am sure it's in some settings but i couldn't find out what could be the issue.

Any suggestion please ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Whatever initializes sqlsrv_connect() it's not loading and that's why you can't call that function.

Comment: You only need the Thread Safe extension in WAMPServer so thats `php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll` The Non Thread Safe version wont run and will cause you issues

Comment: @RiggsFolly  i removed the non thread safe version but still the same issue

Answer (score 2):

At First, Please run MSSQL server database.

In php.ini file, Please added below code

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

and keep two dll file **\ext** folder

To connect database , try

```
$serverName = "serverName\sqlexpress"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"dbName", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I have done the same but still not working. The sqlsrv is still not showing on the php.info too. is there any other setting i need to change in the php.ini ?

Answer (score 2):

Remove "php_" prefix:

```
extension=sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
extension=pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

This worked for me. Thanks for asking this question.